# how to export the display faster to another system in gtk?

Tags: gtk, gdk

I have to run my scrolling gtk application on systems which are in network. But the display is slower when i try to run the application by doing telnet to other systems. Is there any way to render images fast on other systems? Can GdkDisplay be of any use here?

Answer (score 0):

There are server-side (X server) and client-side image buffers. If your image is static it can be pushed to the server. If it is dynamic there are some ways to cache.